# SQL Server Login Using OSQL.exe

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, osql

From Visual Studio 2010 I can connect to my SQL Server Express 2005 instance - by specifying windows authentication.  However, when I use a command like it doesn't work:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>osql -S SQLEXPRESS -U Quixote
nt -P Password.0
[SQL Native Client]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
Server [53].
[SQL Native Client]Login timeout expired
[SQL Native Client]An error has occurred while establishing a connection to
the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by
the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
connections.
```

Incidentally, the above does not actually list my windows name and password - I just substituted examples.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use -U and -P if you want to connect with windows authentication. That is for SQL authentication. Use -E instead:

```
osql -S SQLEXPRESS -E
```

Comment: I needed one more trick to make this work.  It was necessary to write `osql -S .\sqlexpress -E`.  All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 provides several network protocols (like Shared Memory, TCP/IP, named pipes, etc.) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.90).aspx)

Maybe you only have Shared Memory enabled (which your VS is using), and the command line needs a named pipe or TCP/IP to connect.

So, try enabling the other protocols, through the SQL Server Configuration Manager, as described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277/en-us